# Reduce() an object of an element that has already been reduced

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, reduce

I was doing some data manipulation, but I made a mistake and got the wrong data structure, so initially my data is: ([link to data)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xxpgn-w95mpz?file=app%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.ts)

```
const employees = [{
    "EmployeeID": "100A",
    "FirstName": "Downs",
    "aval": [
       {"start": "11-19", "end": "2", "ava": "30", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-20", "end": "2", "ava": "40", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-21", "end": "2", "ava": "50", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-22", "end": "2", "ava": "60", "health": "4"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmployeeID": "100B",
    "FirstName": "Mckenzie",
    "aval": [
       {"start": "11-19", "end": "2", "ava": "1", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-20", "end": "2", "ava": "2", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-21", "end": "2", "ava": "3", "health": "4"},
       {"start": "11-22", "end": "2", "ava": "4", "health": "4"}
    ]
  },

]
```

and would like to get it like:

```
const employees = [
   { "EmployeeID": "100A", "11-19": "30", "11-20": "40", "11-21": "50", "11-22": "60"},
   { "EmployeeID": "100B", "11-19": "1", "11-20": "2", "11-21": "3", "11-22": "4"}
]
```

I've asked around and  this gives me 10 objects instead of two, just need to put those pesky employeeID inside 1 object with all the start values altogether.

```
const res = employees.reduce((acc, { EmployeeID, aval}) => [
      ...acc,
      ...aval.map( ({ start, ava}) => ({ EmployeeID, [start]: ava}) )
    ], []);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your input items and output items are one-to-one, you should use `.map` on `employees` instead of `.reduce`:

```js
const employees=[{"EmployeeID":"100A","FirstName":"Downs","aval":[{"start":"11-19","end":"2","ava":"30","health":"4"},{"start":"11-20","end":"2","ava":"40","health":"4"},{"start":"11-21","end":"2","ava":"50","health":"4"},{"start":"11-22","end":"2","ava":"60","health":"4"}]},{"EmployeeID":"100B","FirstName":"Mckenzie","aval":[{"start":"11-19","end":"2","ava":"1","health":"4"},{"start":"11-20","end":"2","ava":"2","health":"4"},{"start":"11-21","end":"2","ava":"3","health":"4"},{"start":"11-22","end":"2","ava":"4","health":"4"}]},];

const res = employees.map(({ EmployeeID, aval }) => (
  Object.assign(
    { EmployeeID },
    ...aval.map(({ start, ava }) => ({ [start]: ava }))
  )
));
console.log(res);
```

Or, if you wanted to create fewer discarded intermediate objects, you could `reduce` the inner array `aval` instead of `.map`:

```js
const employees=[{"EmployeeID":"100A","FirstName":"Downs","aval":[{"start":"11-19","end":"2","ava":"30","health":"4"},{"start":"11-20","end":"2","ava":"40","health":"4"},{"start":"11-21","end":"2","ava":"50","health":"4"},{"start":"11-22","end":"2","ava":"60","health":"4"}]},{"EmployeeID":"100B","FirstName":"Mckenzie","aval":[{"start":"11-19","end":"2","ava":"1","health":"4"},{"start":"11-20","end":"2","ava":"2","health":"4"},{"start":"11-21","end":"2","ava":"3","health":"4"},{"start":"11-22","end":"2","ava":"4","health":"4"}]},];

const res = employees.map(({ EmployeeID, aval }) => (
  aval.reduce((a, { start, ava }) => {
    a[start] = ava;
    return a;
  }, { EmployeeID })
));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. any recommendations to learn reduce besides or whacky data structures besides the MDN site ?

Comment: Learn reduce, as in, when to use it, or how to use it?

Comment: as in , how and when to implement it?, maybe practice it. it seems like one of the subjects I have the most trouble with. the MDN definition doesnt really help

Comment: When to use: When you need to transform an array into another value, such as a primitive, an object, or another array. Only use `reduce` if neither `.map` nor `.filter` are appropriate. How: when reducing into a primitive, usually you can use the sort of snippets given on MDN, eg `(a, b) => a + b`, just concatenate/add/multiply/etc the accumulator with the next item in the array. But often it's a bit more complicated, like when reducing into an object. The pattern `a[prop] = val; return a;` is *very* common. You might search SO for answers by high-rep users containing `reduce` for examples

Comment: When you need to transform an array into a value (or multiple values), you can almost always use `.reduce` if the other transformation methods (forEach excluded) aren't suitable, feel free to hit me up in chat for details

Comment: I see. didnt know about the pattern , thanks for that.